# positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Tags: python-3.x, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I am just creating a simple recommendation system using cosine similarities, I am trying to recommend the dish. My dataset has Dish_name, Food type (Veg or Non-Veg), Ingredients. I converted ingredients into the vector using TFIDF and used Cosine similarity for the distance.

I have created two user functions. First one to get the food type and filtered out the data from the data frame and applied TFIDF and Cosine Similarity.

```
df =[]
def category(type):

    global tfidf
    global df
    global cosine_similarities

    df = df1.loc[df1['Food Type'] == type]
    df.reset_index(level = 0, inplace = True)
    df = df.head(50)

    tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df = 0, stop_words='english')
    tfidf = tf.fit_transform(df['clean'])

    from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

    cosine_similarities = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

The above code is working and cosine_similarities type is ndarray

My second user define function is to recommend the dish using a cosine similarity score

```
hotels = df['Dish_Name']
#Reverse mapping of the index
indices = pd.Series(df.index, index = df['Dish_Name'])

def recommendations(dish):
    idx = indices[dish]
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_similarities[idx]))
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:5]
    dish_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
    return hotels.iloc[dish_indices]
```

When I run the above code, I am getting the below error

[image]

Please advise

Comment: Which line is throwing an error ?

Comment: @pyOliv   ----> 7     return hotels.iloc[book_indices]